# identifying correct format of a destructor in c++

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

I've encountered this question:

> given class A:

```
class A {
public:
         int size, ** x, *** y;
         A(int _size) {
             size = _size;
             x = new int* [size];
             y = new int** (x);
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                 x[i] = new int(size);
     }
};
```

> identify the correct destructors

there are five options:

> 1

```
~A() {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete x[i];
     delete [] x;
     delete y;
}
```

> 2

```
~A() {
     delete y;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete x[i];
     delete[] x;
}
```

> 3

```
~A() {
     delete y;
     delete [] x;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete x[i];
}
```

> 4

```
~A() {
     delete [] x;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete x[i];
     delete y;
}
```

> 5

```
~A() {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete x[i];
     delete y;
     delete [] x;
}
```

I thought the answer was only the first destructor is safe because it erases the resources from the innermost to the outermost thus ensuring all of the resources are safely deleted and no random data is being deleted.

the correct answer, though, is any of the destructors numbered 1,2,5.

In my understanding, the delete operand frees the memory in the address the pointer refers to, so if we delete the object y before the object x[] then anything can be written in x and we can't delete this information because we don't know what it is.

Am I correct in my understanding?

can you provide me with insight as to why destructors 2 and 5 are viable?

and if 2,5 are viable then why aren't 3 and 4?

Comment: 6) use the proper types for the members that encapsulate memory managment and allow you to follow the rule of 0, ie `~A() {};`

Comment: `*y` holds the *value* of `x`; there is no relationship between the pointers `y` and `x`. `delete`ing `y` first is as safe as `{ int x = 1; int* y = new int(x); delete y; }`.

Comment: `int size, ** x, *** y` is a useless use of pointers...  In C++ don't use new/delete if you don't have to. Have a look at std::vector and what you can do with that. Where are you learning C++ from? your source seems to be outdated. (With current C++ you shouldn't even have to run into the issues you are having)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you deleted `x` you cannot access `x[i]` anymore. This rules out 3 and 4.

The order of deleting `y` and `x` on the other hand does not matter. Here:

```
 y = new int** (x);
```

You dynamically allocate `y` and initialize it with the value of `x`. That means `x == *y`, thats the only relation between the two.

The destructor that you should actually strive for is

```
~A() {}
```

Managing memory is a task on its own. It is enough for 1 class to do. Managing two resources is too much for one class already. You could write wrappers for the members to properly manage the memory such that `A` itself does not need to bother with it. However, this problem has already been solved. There are smart pointers and containers, you just need to pick and use them. I suggest to look at  `std::vector` first, as it covers most usecases.

Answer (score 3):

You are confused by `int **x` and `int ***y`; Note that in your example the results of `x` and `*y` are the same, but `delete y` has no effect on `x`, so you can do it in any order. The only important thing is to `delete x[i]` before `delete[] x`;

In any case the example of constructor and destructor is very bad and you should never arrive to this situation. Go for [rule of 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) instead.